# How to convert all column data type to numeric and character dynamically?

Tags: r

I convert my columns data type manually:

```
data[,'particles'] <- as.numeric(as.character(data[,'particles']))
```

This not ideal as the data may evolve and I won't be sure what species coming, for instance they could be - `"nox", "no2", "co", "so2", "pm10"` and more in the future.

Is there anyway to convert them automatically?

My current dataset:

```
structure(list(particles = structure(c(1L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "11", "1.1", 
    "2", "2.1", "3.1"), class = "factor"), humidity = structure(c(4L, 
    7L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    5L, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0.1", 
    "1", "1.1", "1.3", "21", "2.1", "3"), class = "factor"), timestamp = c(1468833354929, 
    1468833365186, 1468833378458, 1468833538213, 1468833538416, 1468833538613, 
    1468833538810, 1468833538986, 1468833539172, 1468833539358, 1468833539539, 
    1468833554592, 1468833559059, 1468833562357, 1468833566225, 1468833573486, 
    1468840019118, 1468840024950, 1469029568849, 1469029584243, 1469029590530, 
    1469029622391, 1469029623598, 1469245154003, 1469245156533, 1469245156815, 
    1469245157123, 1469245162358, 1469245165911, 1469245170178, 1469245173788
    ), date = structure(c(1468833354.929, 1468833365.186, 1468833378.458, 
    1468833538.213, 1468833538.416, 1468833538.613, 1468833538.81, 
    1468833538.986, 1468833539.172, 1468833539.358, 1468833539.539, 
    1468833554.592, 1468833559.059, 1468833562.357, 1468833566.225, 
    1468833573.486, 1468840019.118, 1468840024.95, 1469029568.849, 
    1469029584.243, 1469029590.53, 1469029622.391, 1469029623.598, 
    1469245154.003, 1469245156.533, 1469245156.815, 1469245157.123, 
    1469245162.358, 1469245165.911, 1469245170.178, 1469245173.788
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "Asia/Singapore")), .Names = c("particles", 
    "humidity", "timestamp", "date"), row.names = c(NA, -31L), class = "data.frame")
```

It has `particles`, `humidity`, `timestamp`, `date`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't know which columns need to be converted beforehand, you can extract that info from your dataframe as follows:

```
vec <- sapply(dat, is.factor)
```

which gives:

```
> vec
particles  humidity timestamp      date 
     TRUE      TRUE     FALSE     FALSE
```

You can then use this vector to do the conversion on the subset with `lapply`:

```
# notation option one:
dat[, vec] <- lapply(dat[, vec], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
# notation option two:
dat[vec] <- lapply(dat[vec], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

If you want to detect both factor and character columns, you can use:

```
sapply(dat, function(x) is.factor(x)|is.character(x))
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option using `mutate_if()` from `dplyr` which allows you to operate on columns for which a predicate returns `TRUE`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate_if(is.factor, funs(as.numeric(as.character(.))))
```

**Note**: This method will work for your [follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38541103/convert-string-to-numberic-all-data-has-been-replaced-when-there-only-on-facto) as well

Comment: This solution is so elegant it should wear a top hat and ride in a Rolls Royce.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table) 
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) if(is.factor(x)) as.numeric(as.character(x)) else x)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The best option is I think *apply*

You can do

```
newD<-apply(data[,"names"], 2,function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

where in "names" you put all the variables you want. Then apply with 2 as second argument will apply the function(x) on all the columns(if you put 1 its by rows) of the first argument. And you can save it as new dataset or rewrite the old one with

```
data[,"names"]<-apply....
```

Comment: It means for the function(x) to be apply for each column. for example colMeans(data) is equivalent to apply(data,2, mean) and for rowMeans(data) you can use equivalently apply(data,1,mean). Do you see the difference?

Comment: @teelou It's `MARGIN` argument. `2` means function will be applied over columns of the data frame. If you want to apply a function over rows, you'll write 1.

Comment: @Narendra and Jan for the explanation.

Comment: `apply` is not the best option.  It is designed for use on matrices and will turn this data frame into a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Use `lapply`:

```
cols <- c("particles", "nox", ...)

data[,cols] <- lapply(data[,cols], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```